# How could I draw different x-axis (set_categories) on openpyxl with python

Tags: python, excel, graph, charts, openpyxl

I would like to draw with one y value with two x-axis(x1,x2 array). 
But It is not look like possible in Openpyxl.

```
x1 = [6.60 ,6.87 ,7.06 ,6.62 ,7.28 ]
x2 = [4.29 ,5.14 ,5.34 ,4.57 ,4.81 ]

p1 = [30.95 ,30.93 ,31.13 ,30.98 ,31.17]

for index , value in enumerate(p1):

    ws.cell(row = index + 1, column = 1, value = p1[index])
    ws.cell(row = index + 1, column = 2, value = x1[index])
    ws.cell(row = index + 1, column = 3, value = x2[index])

x_axis1 = Reference(ws, min_col = 2, min_row = 1, max_row = 5)
x_axis2 = Reference(ws, min_col = 3, min_row = 1, max_row = 5)
y_axis = Reference(ws, min_col = 1, min_row = 1, max_row = 5)
```

And I would like to get the Figure like below
[image]

I like to draw one same y-axis with two different x-axis in one figure. 
But I can not find the ways to use different x-axis in openpyxl. 
Is is possible to use?